# How long does web3.eth.personal.newAccount() keep a new account unlocked?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, accounts

I've created a new account on my local geth using web3.js library like this

```
web3.eth.personal.newAccount("1234", (error, address) = {
    // some code
    myContractInstance.methods.myMethod().send({from: address});
});
```

I noticed the newly created account was unlocked because I was able to send a transaction and execute `myMethod()` from the new account address without any "account locked" errors.

Is there a way to find out how long the new account will remain unlocked or does the new account remain unlocked indefinitely (until I explicitly lock it)?